# For loop with two different indexes in python?

Tags: java, python

I have the following loop in java

```
double f,x,y;
int i;
for(i=0, f=0.01; i<100 && f<1.0; i++,f+=0.01)
{
     x=y*i+y*f;
     system.out.println("x = " +x,i , f);
}
```

But I would like to have 2 different indexes at once in it.

Comment: SO is not java to python converter. Try to write in python, if you are facing any issue/error, ask here. we are happy to help.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one

```
for i, j in zip(range(100), [(x/10) for x in range(100)]):
  #print (i, j)
  #your code
```

Answer (score 1):

For this example, you can define `f` in terms of `i`:

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    f = (i + 1) / 100.0
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a while loop instead.

```
f = -1
i = 0
x = -1
y = -1
while (i < 100 and f < 1.0):
    x = y * i + y * f
    print('x = {} {} {}'.format(x, i, f))
    i += 1
    f += 0.01
```